Noisy internal microcontroller DAC
I built a prototype 2-layers PCB with an ATSAMD51J19 microcontroller, a simple LPF and an opamp connected to the internal 12bit DAC of the microcontroller.
The code (an Arduino sketch) uses a DDS routine and a 16-bit timer with interrupts to generate waveforms at various audio frequencies, outputting them through the internal DAC via DMA. The main "loop" includes various functions for managing different peripherals (mainly shift registers and I2C sensors, not connected on the prototype).

However, in addition to the expected waveform, I am also getting a noise/whistling sound at about 500Hz, approximately -50dB relative to the main waveform peak. That noise is there even if I produce no output from the DAC and even if I completely disable it via software.
I noticed that if I remove all the code from the main loop, the noise disappears, and if I put a delay() in the loop, the frequency of the noise gets lower.
Using an oscilloscope, I observed that the noise is already present on the DAC pin, also if not connected to any other circuitry after, so it doesn’t seem to be introduced later on the PCB. And by the way, rotating the potentiometer fully CCW completely removes the noise, so it's not coming from the opamp.
I would also rule out the PSU circuitry, because I tried with various ways (USB only, external regulated PSU, battery only, external 3.3V and 5V regulators) but the noise is always there.
This is the layout, there is a ground plane (top and bottom layer) under the microcontroller. The only connections from/to that section are the DAC output, the +supply input and the ground.
I'm sure I made some mistakes with the layout, but I can't understand what


You have traces routed over cuts in the ground plane, no ground plane at all under a very high frequency switching converter, you omitted the input/output capacitors on your linear regulators, and lots of the decoupling capacitors are far from the things they're decoupling.  You probably have all kinds of noise on the power supply to that DAC from all of those things.   This might be a good choice for a 4 layer board with solid power/ground planes under everything.
